# Can I call mysql stored procedure have input paramater in C# without pamameter?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, procedure

I want convert stored procedure from MSSQL to MySQL. In MSSQL we can set default value for user-define parameter, so we mustn't call stored with list parameter. But in MySQL I can't do that.

For example:
**MSSQL**:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[ABC]
 @A datetime = null
```

=> We can: `exec ABC`

**MySQL**:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ABC`(
    A datetime
)
```

=> We must: `call ABC(value)`

Anyway to call MySQL stored procedure in C# without list parameter? Because I don't want change my C# code....

Comment: MySQL does not support optional parameters. Unless you always want to use default values, you *have to* change your C# code.

Comment: "MySQL does not support optional parameters" - This make my task harder  (facepalm). Thanks for your support!